# Have to display data, from django using form and optional value

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

**I am trying to display data from my models to HTML page by using form and field optional(value).
Bat noting is displaying to my HTML page and the filter is not working:**

**This is my modles.py file:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class TaskCategory(models.Model):
     category_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.category_title

class Post(models.Model):
     task_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     task_discription = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     task_category = models.ForeignKey(TaskCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     recommended_tools = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     budget = models.CharField(max_length=250)

     def __str__(self):
       return self.task_title + ' | ' + self.task_discription + ' | ' + str(self.task_category) + ' | ' + self.recommended_tools + ' | ' + self.budget
```

**urls.py file:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('PostPage/', PostPageView, name ='post_page'),
]
```

**view.py file:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView
from .models import Post, TaskCategory
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def is_valid_queryparam(param):
     return param != '' and param is not None

def PostPageView(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    category = TaskCategory.objects.all()
    category = request.GET.get('category')
    if is_valid_queryparam(category) and category != 'Choose...':
        post = post.filter(category_title=category)
        context = {
            'post': Post.objects.all(),
            'category': TaskCategory.objects.all()
          }

    return render(request, "post_page.html", context)
```

Comment: 1) you define your context inside the if (what if condition is false it never gets defined then..). 2) You filter but still write `'post': Post.objects.all(),` it should be `'post': post`. Also you first assign `TaskCategory.objects.all()` to category and immediately after assign `request.GET.get('category')`.

Comment: @ Abdul Aziz Barkat I did something like this:                                                          
    def PostPageView(request):
          posts = Post.objects.all()
          context = {
               'posts': Post.objects.all(),
               'category': TaskCategory.objects.all()
           }
           category = request.GET.get('category')

           if is_valid_queryparam(category) and category != 'Choose...':
               posts = posts.filter(task_category=category)
               return posts

           return render(request, "post_page.html", context)

Comment: and sill getting an error when I submit:                                                                
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'stolar'.